# Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' Spring SAML

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, single-page-application, spring-saml

We are implementing SSO using Spring saml, after getting authenticated when user gets redirected to application we are getting following issue

```
Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'
```

following is my code. login.html

```
<form class="form" role="form" ng-submit="login($event)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Login</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Your login" ng-model="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Your password"
                       ng-model="password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="rememberMe">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" ng-model="rememberMe" checked>
                    <span>Automatic Login</span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Authenticate</button>
        </form>
```

index.html

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="_csrf_parameter" content="_csrf" />
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="X-CSRF-TOKEN" />
    <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Secutityconfig.java

```
@Bean
public CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() 
{ 
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository(); 
    repository.setSessionAttributeName("_csrf");
    return repository; 
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
    .and()
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
```

Please guide mt what wrong I am doing.

Thanks & Regards
Mahesh